# Import data from text file in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, import

I have 100 comma separated longitude and latitude values in a text file. I want to mark all these 100 points on GEE maps and see where they lie. This is the script I am using for marking the point:

```js
var point1 = ee.Geometry.Point([x, y]);
Map.addLayer(point1, {color: 'cyan'}, 'geodesic polygon');
```

where x and y are longitude and latitude values respectively. I followed [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251879/how-to-import-handdrawn-polygon-using-json-file-in-earthengine) with a similar query but here the answer suggests to get the json text using `print(geometry)` but my problem is that I have generated these 100 points through a Matlab code (instead of generating them directly on GEE) according to some analysis so I don't possibly have a JSON data for them. Thus I need wanted to know how can I import these points from a local text file and work with them on GEE?

Comment: Why not just convert your csv to json externally? https://www.csvjson.com/csv2json

Comment: Or export them as a shapefile and load them as an (Table) asset. Any GIS can do this.

Comment: You are probalby fine with comma seperated lists using: ee.Geometry.MultiPoint(coords, proj) [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/4e05fb641d51f41e7ec3b68026ae9a9b). Could you show an example of ~10 points using a EarthEngine link?

Comment: @Kuik I'm sorry but I don't know how to import these points from my local file on code.editor in the first place.

Comment: @Jon to export them as a shapefile I again need to read these points from my local text file to code.editor.

Comment: @Prachi I don't understand the problem. You have a text file containing coordinates. You can pull that into a GIS, export it as a shapefile, and upload it to GEE as a table asset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it after suggestions in the comment.
I exported it as a shapefile using QGIS and then imported it as a table.